How do i reference a column in a join?
I was expecting the join to replace the ID 8n document table with the DocType.TypeName
This query yields 1 row as expected
SELECT * FROM `DocType` WHERE `ID`            
=1 

ID TypeName 
1  PDF

This query using join
SELECT            
    *            
FROM            
    Document            
LEFT JOIN(DocType) ON (            
        Doctype.ID = Document.DocType           
)

Gives an error #1054 - Unknown column 'Doctype.ID' in 'on clause'
The first query shows DocType.ID is a valid column... Is there a different way to represent a column other than table.column?

Can you please query SELECT VERSION(); and add the result to your question? I tested your query on MySQL 8.4 and I get no error.

show us create tables for both tables and like bill said also the version you are using

What's with all those brackets?

Can you try the query like this? SELECT  *  FROM  Document  LEFT JOIN DocType ON  DocType.ID = Document.DocType;

'Is there a different way to represent a column other than table.column?' - yes there is ,aliases, but is not pertinent to the code you have provided and assuming both tables are indeed tables and not views are in the same db, I can't reproduce your issue either.

VERSION()
8.0.36

That worked Mustafa!

@JosephKlug In SQL each separate char (including spaces, parenthesis and so on) have its own meaning. Any attempt to make the code beautiful may kill the query.

@JosephKlug Ok. Glad it helped you. Then I'm adding this as an answer so others who need it can easily access it.

Thank you again I  haven't done much with SQL in over 20 years...

You need to write the SQL query in the correct syntax. Remove the parentheses and add as follows and the problem will be solved.
SELECT  *  FROM  Document  LEFT JOIN DocType ON  DocType.ID = Document.DocType;

